# android sound gets disabled after sometime

Tags: android, service, audio, handler, android-service

i want to check how the service feature set in android works. to check it, i have a controller class that will start the service. in the service i have a handler that executes a function every minute.the function plays the sound. everything works well when the screen is on but after the screen goes dark(off), the sound is heard about 2-3 times (2-3 minutes) and then it stops...
any idea why? and how can i make it (execute the sound function)work every minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the phone goes into sleep mode, so does the cpu.  Some recievers may wake the phone up causing your sounds to be heard.  Take a look into [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and try to wake your phone(and cpu) up when you want to hear the sound.

Comment: @ninjasense...thank you for that..but isn't using PowerManager restricted for general developers. please let me know if you have used it without having to root the phone or compile own firmware

Comment: @raqz - No it is not, you will have to add a permission to your android manifest though...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: @ninjasense..thank you.it worked. but now i am facing a new issue, will create a new question in SO for the benefit of others

Comment: @ninjasense..kindly have a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286947/wake-locks-android-service-recurring