# How to prevent mediaplayer to stop when screen goes off?

Tags: android, media-player, screen, instantiationexception

I have a mediaplayer in a `Music` class that is called from another secondary `Activity`. It works fine.

But when screen goes off (either by timeout or button), the music stops playing, and when coming back and try to close the activity the program goes to "App Not Responding", because an `IllegalStateException` at a query like `mediaplayer.isPlaying()`.

How can I prevent the mediaplayer to stop when screen goes off?

Does it have to be through a service??

Assuming that the answer is yes, I tried to convert the `Music` class into a service (see below). I also added `<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Music" />` into the `Manifest.xml`, and I am calling the `Music` class like this:

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Music.class));
Music track = Music(fileDescriptor);
```

The only 2 new lines in the main Activity are `startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Music.class));` and `stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Music.class));`, together with the corresponding imports.

But now I get `InstantiationException` error because `can't instantiate class` when trying to start the service. What am I missing?

This is the exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.floritfoto.apps.ave.Music:                                                                             java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.floritfoto.apps.ave.Music; no empty constructor                                                                   
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2249)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.floritfoto.apps.ave.Music; no empty constructor
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2246)
E/AndroidRuntime(16642):    ... 10 more
```

and this is the Music.class:

```
package com.floritfoto.apps.ave;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Music extends Service implements OnCompletionListener{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean isPrepared = false;

    //// TEstes de servico
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        info("Servico criado!");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        info("Servico fudeu!");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        info("Servico started!");
    }   
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void info(String txt) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    //// Fim testes de servico

    public Music(FileDescriptor fileDescriptor){
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try{
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            isPrepared = true;
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load music, uh oh!");
        }
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        synchronized(this){
            isPrepared = false;
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) return;
        try{
            synchronized(this){
                if(!isPrepared){
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                }
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        synchronized(this){
            isPrepared = false;
        }
    }

    public void switchTracks(){
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public boolean isLooping() {
        return mediaPlayer.isLooping();
    }

    public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(isLooping);
    }

    public void setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight) {
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return String.valueOf((int)(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000));
    }
    public void dispose() {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you read the documentation on how to use a service ?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @deefactorial Of course not! I just want to implement the most basic mediaplayer ever made!! I don't want (and expect do not need) to know all its subtleties. I am just trying to follow the (famous?) marakana example here http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html. What I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line from Logcat is the important one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.floritfoto.apps.ave.Music; no empty constructor
```

Your service needs another constructor that takes no arguments:

```
public Music() {
    super("Music");
}
```

**EDIT**:

Using a service is the correct approach if you want to keep the music playing when the screen is off. However, the phone will try to sleep when the screen is off, and this can interrupt your `MediaPlayer`.

The most reliable solution is to use a [partial WakeLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091270/how-can-i-keep-my-android-service-running-when-the-screen-is-turned-off) to prevent the device from sleeping while you're playing music. Be sure to release the `WakeLock` properly when you're not actively playing music; otherwise the battery will drain.

You may also want to use `startForeground()`, which will reduce the risk of your service being killed when there is memory pressure. It will also create a nice user experience by showing a persistent notification when your service is running.

Instantiating the `Music` class with `Music track = Music(fileDescriptor);` is probably doing some harm. A better approach is to pass the file descriptor as an `Extra` in the `Intent` that you pass to `startService()`:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, Music.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("ServiceFileDescriptor", fileDescriptor);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Then, retrieve the file descriptor from that same `Intent` when it's passed to your service's `onStartCommand()` method:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStart();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    // NOTE: The next line will vary depending on the data type for the file
    // descriptor. I'm assuming that it's an int.
    int fileDescriptor = bundle.getIntExtra("ServiceFileDescriptor");
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
        ...
    ...
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

A few of things to note here. I've moved the code from your original constructor (which should be removed) into `onStartCommand()`. You can remove the `onStart()` method as well, since it will only be called on pre-2.0 devices. If you want to support modern Android versions, you'll need to use `onStartCommand()` instead. Finally, the `START_STICKY` return value will ensure that the service stays running until you call `stopService()` from your activity.

**EDIT 2**:

Using a service enables your users to move between activities without interrupting the `MediaPlayer`. You don't have much control over how long an `Activity` will stay in memory, but an active `Service` (especially if you call `startForeground()`) won't be killed unless there is very strong memory pressure.

To interact with the `MediaPlayer` after the service is started, you have a couple of options. You can pass additional commands to the service by creating `Intent`s and using the action string (and/or some extras) to tell the service what you would like it to do. Just call `startActivity()` again with the new `Intent`, and `onStartCommand()` will be called in the service, at which point you can manipulate the `MediaPlayer`. The second option is to use a [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) (example [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Local_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example)) and to bind/unbind each time you enter/leave an activity that needs to communicate with the service. Using a bound service "feels" as though you're directly manipulating the service, but it's also more complex since you need to manage binding and unbinding.

Comment: You mean following the line `public Music(FileDescriptor fileDescriptor){`? I did it, and got "The constructor Service(String) is undefined", and asked me to remove the "Music". I did it, and get the very same `InstantiationException`. :(

Comment: Now I understood what you meant (but I had to delete the `"Music"` inside the parenthesis). But then I still get the same problem: I see in the logcat that the mediaplayer gets disconnected when screen is off and I get `IllegalStateException` when query `mediaPlayer.isPlaying`, like if no service was being executed. :(

Comment: Maybe Services are not what I need to solve this, and there is some other much simpler solution?? Please help...

Comment: Or maybe the problem is that the mediaPlayer is not created when service is created...? :o(

Comment: Yes, that's part of the problem. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: MMmmm... beginning to understand! While trying to implement your solution, please be (even more) kind enough to answer two little questions: 1) If the problem was the wakelock, why to use services at all, i.e., why not just add a wakelock to the program I already had? 2) How do I interact with the Music.mediaPlayer? I tried both Music.mediaPlayer.getDuration() and Music.getDuration() and got null pointer exception. Thanks!!

Comment: Got it. I will implement the service as you suggest. Thanks a zillion for your time and kindness!!!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I still don't get how to interact with the server. I started the service with Intent, bundle extras (for the filename), and startService(). But for example how do I know that the player is playing, or the song duration? Thanks!

Comment: Once you've started the service with an Intent, you can bind to it and call any public methods that you've defined on your `Service`. For example, you could define methods that get the playback status or the duration of the current song. Please take a look at the example link near the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I implemented a bound service as you suggested, and everything is working well. In case anyone needs the actual code, I can post it. Thanks A LOT for all the help and patience!!!! :o)

Comment: @LuisA.Florit, yes please do post the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

as an option you can keep the screen activated to maintain the MediaPlayer reproducing the media:

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```