# not running when mobile is locked

Tags: java, android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I keep my Android service running when the screen is turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091270/how-can-i-keep-my-android-service-running-when-the-screen-is-turned-off)

In my application. i call web services to check updates on webserver that is sended by android application.
My application is not running when mobile is locked and i want to run my application in background.
I'll be thankful for your advices

Comment: You need to use a Service. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html. Activity-Based Classes will not run when Screen is off

Comment: use WakeLocks or Service to get this done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that when your application doesn't have focus (I assume that you are using an `Activity`) it is paused or stopped.

You can use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) if you want to run something in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that runs in the background or for updates you can use push mechanism rather then the pull mechanism. You can use [Google cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) for push notification.