# Make app/service "run after screen turns off" ? -Android-

Tags: android

i a'm completly android programing noob

i'am working on developing "Androrat" (this project is not mine i had found it over the internet)

when the screen turns off the connection is lost 
how can i make the processes/service always running ?

I had googled some and found that i have to include a partial_wake_timer
I want the code and where i have to enter it ?

I a'm completely noob please bair with me

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/102520949/Untitled.jpg

or maybe a kind person can help me over team-viewer ?

Answer (score 1):

A partial `WakeLock` is what you want. It will hold the CPU open, even if the screen is off.

**To acquire:**

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

**To release:**

```
wakeLock.release();
```

This answer was taken from this link:
[How can I keep my Android service running when the screen is turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091270/how-can-i-keep-my-android-service-running-when-the-screen-is-turned-off)

Next time, please search more deeply.