# Best voice recognition algorithm for android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-speech-api

I am planning to build a voice recognition app in android where the app does few things when the user says a particular word.

I came across a tutorial of Levenshtein Distance algorithm in android for speech recognition. 
It works fine but when there is music playing around or when the device is kept at a distance it does not recognize what I say.

I would like to know if there is any good open source algorithm  for voice recognition which we could use in our android app? or should we design our own algorithm?

Any links to good study material or help on this will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Voice recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026491/android-voice-recognition)

Comment: try this http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-voice-recognition-tutorial.html

Comment: @LOG_TAG thanks for the link the question asked is basically what I had in my mind:)