# When and why PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK is required?

Tags: android, service, android-wake-lock

All other wake locks makes sense e.g. developer want screen not to go off while performing something. But in partial wake lock [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) says that :

> If you hold a partial wake lock, the CPU will continue to run,
>   regardless of any display timeouts or the state of the screen and even
>   after the user presses the power button. In all other wake locks, the
>   CPU will run, but the user can still put the device to sleep using the
>   power button.

Does that mean while performing some operation CPU can go off? Is it required to acquire wake lock in a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean while performing some operation CPU can go off? Is it required to acquire wake lock in a service?

Of [course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091270/how-can-i-keep-my-android-service-running-when-the-screen-is-turned-off) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286947/wake-locks-android-service-recurring) - for the power off button) ! Things are even more complicated if you are trying to *start* your service *while the device is asleep*. You most probably won't make it. Have a look at Commonsware [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) - the notion is that using an alarm manager Receiver (which holds a wake lock) you must afterwards get a (static) wakelock while still in `onReceive()` to keep awake.