# Android countdown timer application

Tags: android, android-alarms, countdowntimer

I have countdown timer ticking in service. It updates UI through broadcast.
All works good, but I don't know how to wake device if it were in sleep state (user pressed the power button or enough time elapsed)?

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried. Or at least what you have searched for.

Comment: Well, I've seen the code of deskClock (the default android clock app).
If I'm correct, they don't use service for countdowntimer.

I can't find any thorough manual on how to work with power managment in android, and how to wake device from sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use wake lock to prevent CPU to go to sleep, look at this question
[Wake locks android service recurring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286947/wake-locks-android-service-recurring) and this [How can I keep my Android service running when the screen is turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091270/how-can-i-keep-my-android-service-running-when-the-screen-is-turned-off)

Comment: Well, I'm using partial wake lock and my service is not killed so far, when I'm press power button.
But how to turn the screen on and would my activity started from service with intent be really started?